# GraphQL Semi join : Filter condition on semi join query gives error for 2 specific fields

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-development, graphql

```
    const whereClause = `where: {
        Id: { inq: {
            Apttus_Config2__AssetLineItem__c : { and : [
                          { Apttus_Config2__AssetStatus__c : { eq : "Activated"  } },
                          { or : 
                          [
                              { Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r : { Name : { like : "%${main.searchText}%" } } },
                             { Order_Number__c : { like : "%${main.searchText}%" } },
                              { Licensed_User__r : { PEOPLE_CD__c : { like : "%${main.searchText}%" } } }
                          ] }
                      ]
            },
            ApiName:"Agreement__c"
        }
    }
    }
    orderBy: { 
        LastModifiedDate : { order : DESC }
    }`
```

In above code when use Licensed_User__r.PEOPLE_CD__c in filter condition it gives below error :

**There is an error [{"errorType":"adapterError","error":[{"extensions":{"ErrorType":"DataFetchingException"},"locations":[{"column":7,"line":4}],"message":"Exception while fetching data (/uiapi/query/Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c) : null","paths":["uiapi","query","Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c"]}]}]**

If i use { Licensed_User__r : { Name : { like : "%${main.searchText}%" } } } then it works fine. People code is the simple string field i read through the documentation i don't see any limitation mentioned like this. Please help.

[image: field type that is causing issue]